# Error saving decimal value from SQL SERVER to RDB

Tags: sql-server-2012, openquery, oracle-rdb

i use openquery to save values from sql server to RDB through ORACLE RDB DRIVER ,ODBC

```
  insert into OPENQUERY([RDB_ODBC_ACCOUNTING],
  'select     *         from test') 
  (f1) values( 0.001)
```

the value saved in rdb=  100
any suggest?

Comment: you might have to check the corresponding data type in RDB,that corresponds to float in sqlserver

Comment: if i save 1.001 or 0.123 it will save correctly   but just if it 0.0xxxx